# Listview with Checkbox and a textview

Tags: android, listview

In my application i have a listview with a checkbox and textview in a row and also a button at the bottom of the screen.When user clicks the button i have to get the selected item in the listview in an array..I tried out this

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/testbutton"
        android:text="OK" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listforSetting"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_above="@id/testbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity:

```
String[] item = common.context.getInstance().getCategoryitem();
    String[] name;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listforsetting);
        final ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listforSetting);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.testbutton);

        lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, item));
        lView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);



        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SparseBooleanArray checked = lView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
                    if (checked.get(i))
                    {
                        name[i]=lView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                        System.out.println("item="+name[i]);
                    }

                }


            }
        });
```

But it is showing as null pointer exception(when clicking the button)..Please help me to solve this.

My logcat:

```
01-01 12:17:20.817: E/AndroidRuntime(584): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.newspaper.ListforSetting$1.onClick(ListforSetting.java:39)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-01 12:17:20.847: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Thanks CapDroid..I will post it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to initialize `name` array

Comment: use comment instead of answer for suggestion..

Comment: Answer should be good explaintation with some code..

Comment: I don't think that initializing an Array is that much of a complexity that it needs to be shown, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: okey.. should be your point is right but never give single line answer..

Comment: Thanks Mohamed_AbdAllah..Chilly mistake doen by me..Forget to initialize..

Answer (score 1):

You didn't intilize your `name[]`

```
name[] = new String[item.length] ;
for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
{
     if (checked.get(i))
     {
         name[i]=lView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
         System.out.println("item="+name[i]);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the items of `item[]` array? Make sure the `item[]` array contains the list of the items which you are adding in it. And also initialize the `String[] name=null;` or `String[] name=new String[];`